Is it GDPR compliant to require Digital Rights Management software to access a privacy policy?
Suppose a data controller provided a privacy policy, detailing the information that a data subject must have or be provided with under the various articles of the GDPR, including 13, 14, 15, 22 and 45.  If this is available on the open web over "normal" https then their responsibilities are discharged, as would those whom they transfer data with.
If this privacy policy was only available by the download and installation of Digital Rights Management (DRM) software would their responsibilities be appropriately discharged?  It is worth noting that the primary (only?) choice for many has absolute contractual requirements, significant privacy implications and at least philosophical security issues.
The example that prompted this question is the privacy policy of Falcon Sensor from CrowdStrike which in this question I wrongly attributed to a "Free Registration Wall".  It is very far from certain that this has anything to do with DRM, I do not know enough to even say if this is what it would look like, certainly not enough to figure out if this is the cause.  However "visible on Safari, not on firefox/brave" is what I would expect to happen if it was.  It does not really matter, if this is legal then it could be a useful tool for companies to track their users, if not people should be aware of it.

The right to information in Art 13 is probably the most relevant one because it has no real exceptions. This information must be provided when information is collected directly from data subjects. If the privacy notice only covers processing activities that only happen when DRM-controlled content is played, I don't see a problem. Similarly, it would be OK to disclose privacy notices for a subscription service only as part of the signup process (e.g. just before a customer account is created). But the main privacy notice for a public website, which processes personal data from all visitors, …

@amon I would have thought Art 14 (in this case 14.1 (f) is particularly relevant) would be equally relevant in the case this was a second party (eg. EMIS in the UK.  If the GP's were relying on the patients being able to access this data to avoid providing the Art 14 data at the time of data transfer then they are in breach.

CrowdStrike (CS) would have obligations under Art 14 if they were to collect personal data via third parties, while acting as a data controller. It is not clear to me (a) that the Falcon Sensor product processes personal data, (b) that CS acts as the data controller for this processing, and (c) that the linked privacy notice covers Falcon Sensor. A likelier path to demonstrate a violation is to assume that the linked notice is to cover processing activities for serving the website, for which CS definitely is the data controller. My inability to access that notice doesn't seem very compliant.
